# Azure Automation Credentials using Azure Key Vault secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to create an Azure Automation Credential asset which links to an Azure Key Vault secret? Similar question for a Certificate in Azure Automation.

I want to be able to store my passwords and such all in one place, the Key Vault, so that when I change it I don't have to change it in a bunch of places.  I cannot find any documentation that indicates this is possible though.  Am I missing it?

Thank you for any suggestions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't link a Credential asset directly to Key Vault, however it should be possible to write a script that connects to Key Vault and updates the appropriate Automation Credentials from there.

This could either be fired on a schedule, a webhook, or by picking up Key Vault events from the new Event Grid (presuming they are currently wired up)

Comment: Thank you. Hadn't thought about that, but that's a good idea.